# How to remove Export option from Sales/Order grid?

Tags: event-observer, magento-1.8, order-grid, user-roles

I want to remove the following from sale order grid:

- New Order RSS
- Export to:
- MassAction block

for a particular admin user role.

I currently use `adminhtml_block_html_before` event to remove the MassAction block:

> my observer method:

```
    public function salesOrderVendorLayout($evt){
        $tabBlock = $evt->getBlock();
        if($tabBlock instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid){
            $tabBlock->setMassactionIdField('');
        }
    }
```

[image]

> My Questions:

1. Is this the right way to remove mass action block?
2. How can I remove the remaining two blocks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to remove the rss link and the export types through an observer.
For example, the code that shows the export types is this:

```
<?php if($this->getExportTypes()): ?>
    <td class="export a-right">
        <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/icon_export.gif') ?>" alt="" class="v-middle"/>&nbsp; <?php echo $this->__('Export to:') ?>
        <select name="<?php echo $this->getId() ?>_export" id="<?php echo $this->getId() ?>_export" style="width:8em;">
        <?php foreach ($this->getExportTypes() as $_type): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $_type->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $_type->getLabel() ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
        <?php echo $this->getExportButtonHtml() ?>
    </td>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The only way to make it not appear is to make `getExportTypes` return `null` or `false` and the method looks like this:

```
public function getExportTypes()
{
    return empty($this->_exportTypes) ? false : $this->_exportTypes;
}
```

`_exportTypes` is protected and the only public methods that access it are `getExportTypes` for retrieving and `addExportType` for adding a new export type. There is no way to remove them. The same goes for RSS lists.
Here is what I would do in your case. I would rewrite the orders grid block `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid` and add the following methods:

```
public function getExportTypes(){
    return false;
}
public function getRssLists(){
    return false;
}
protected function _prepareMassaction(){
    return $this;
}
```

Even better, I would implement a way to still be able to show them by changing a config setting in the backend (if needed).

```
public function getExportTypes(){
    if (!Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('some/config/path')){ //if some flag is not set let it behave as default.
        return parent::getExportTypes();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I see three ways:

## The easy one: CSS

Just add a new css file and hide everything you want

## Change the template

There is a standard template which is used for every grid and its container:

```
/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid/container.phtml
/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid.phtml
```

Just change the template in your own `layout.xml` file, copy the template and remove the parts you don't want

## Rewrite the block

Rewrite the block `\Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid` and change the method `\Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid::_prepareMassaction` to do nothing

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I did:

```
class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid{

    protected $_idArray = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->_idArray = Mage::helper('mymodule')->getUserInfo();
    }

    public function getExportTypes(){
        if($this->_idArray['user_role'] == 'xyz'){
            return false;
        } else{
            return $this->_exportTypes;
        }
    }

    public function getRssLists(){
        if($this->_idArray['user_role'] == 'xyz'){
            return false;
        } else{
            return $this->_rssLists;
        }
    }

    protected function _prepareMassaction(){
        if($this->_idArray['user_role'] == 'xyz'){
            return $this;
        } else{
            parent::_prepareMassaction();
        }
    }

}
```

where `getUserInfo()` is my helper class method which will get the **user id** and **user role** from **admin/session**.